# how to get panorama in 360 degree sphere view?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on an app which capture multiple images and show them in panorama view.But i want to view these images in spherical view inside panorama.That i ma not able to do.Please help.

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform Rotation="360"></CompositeTransform>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <phone:Panorama>
        <phone:Panorama.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="360"></CompositeTransform>
        </phone:Panorama.RenderTransform>
        <phone:PanoramaItem>
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="/images/05.jpg"></Image>

        </phone:PanoramaItem>
        <phone:PanoramaItem>
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="/images/06.jpg"></Image>

        </phone:PanoramaItem>
        <phone:PanoramaItem>
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="/images/07.jpg"></Image>

        </phone:PanoramaItem>
        <phone:PivotItem>
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="/images/08.jpg"></Image>

        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```